# how to create a static view page which gets result from a content type?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

Good day,
I am wondering how do i create a static page, which displays the result of content types data?
its like this: a user will fill a content type called "books" and insert data into fields like (author, type of book, published,localization).
the type of book will be a taxonomy, which will determine if the book is a magazine, novel or a research.

think of the result page as an excel file, which will have a book, and its sub categorized into field of result numbers.

my point is, i want to create a static page, which will show result of the following:

1. how many research books available. (a field will be based on taxonomy term)
2. what are their localizations, foreign, or local.
3. [image: static page should show result like this once data is inserted from content type]

i know the a math operated result could use [views_calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc) module, but i wanted it as an independent page viewing the report, not to mention that not all will require math operation.

so once a user fills in the content types field, result is updated to the static view page automatically (like a report) to tell what and how many books types were inserted and what are they. please refer to the pic.

to clarify further, in database coding, i would execute my intended report for 1 result as from content type like this: "select * from books where type="magazine" and published= "yes"

so result will show how many magazines published, as in the pic.

i heard about [forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module, but it seemed bit too complex for my task, which i think is simple. but im not sure.

im new to the web development era, i used to do basic java SE so im trying to avoid coding everything(which is my last option).

hope i made it clear.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to look at some of the typical "page layout" modules, such as these ones (excerpts from their project pages):

- [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds).

  > ... allows you to take full control over how your content is displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views, comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your way through dozens of template files. A predefined list of layouts (D7 only) is available for even more drag and drop fun!
- [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels).

  > ... allows a site administrator to create customized layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag and drop content manager that lets you visually design a layout and place content within that layout. Integration with other systems allows you to create nodes that use this, landing pages that use this, and even override system pages such as taxonomy and the node page so that you can customize the layout of your site with very fine grained permissions.

Not sure if *Display Suite* will be sufficient for all your needs, but *Panels* will pretty sure be helpfull. Possibly also with 'mini-panels' added to that.

Be prepared however to invest some time in learning about these amazing modules. A great resource for learning about Panels is the (free) video training about [Learn Page manager](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-page-manager). *Panels* uses 'Page manager', which is one of the sub-modules of [Chaos tool suite (ctools)](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools)).

And after you become familiar with these modules, you may want to consider using [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) to create special (mini?) reports to be shown in (eg) a block on your page. Possibly also using Forena's integration with the [BEAN](https://www.drupal.org/project/bean) module (another module to add to your list of modules to be reviewed ...). For more details about this integration, refer to Forena's [Site Building Guide](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.sitebuilding#bean).

Comment: oh i see, i'll be looking into those two. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Great to read this helped! By the way: you're only 2 points away from being allowed to start "upvoting". If you want to soon reach that "permission" also, then consider "suggesting an edit" to any question, answer, tag wiki, or tag excerpt. If you succeed (= if the edit gets approved) you earn +2 points for each of them ...

Comment: got it, i guess i'll have to go through forena at the end. i'll look into your suggestion. Thanks again :D